# Prove $c$ satisfies the integral

Tags: calculus, integration

If $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, show that there exists $c \in [0,1]$ such that

$$f(c)=\int_0^1 2t  f(t) \text{d}t.$$

So it's pretty clear to me that I have to use Intermediate Value Theorem and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but I can't quite get the trick done.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Since $f$ is continuous there exist $a,b\in [0,1]$ such that $f(a)\le f(x)\le f(b), \:\forall x\in [0,1].$ Now,

$$t\in[0,1]\implies tf(a)\le t f(x)\le t f(b).$$ So

$$2f(a)\int_0^1 tdt \le 2\int_0^1 tf(t)dt\le 2f(b)\int_0^1 tdt.$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: yes, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Using first mean value theorem for integration (you can find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)) we have that exists a $c\in\left[0,1\right]$ such that $$\int_{0}^{1}2tf\left(t\right)dt=f\left(c\right)\int_{0}^{1}2tdt=f\left(c\right).$$